# Fazer o código esperar por um input do usuário para rodar uma ação, e logo depois pedir o input novamente

Tags: javascript

Alô, me deparei com um problema ao tentar desenvolver um algoritmo pra um pequeno rpg baseado em texto(baseado no curso de Python da SoloLearn) em Javascript, e tenho tentado pensar numa maneira de passar por cima dele sem quebrar a lógica, que seria "**o usuário insere um texto, uma mensagem retorna por ele, e novamente, o código aguarda pelo input do usuário**", e por aí vai, alguem pode me ajudar a solucionar?, vou deixar um trecho do código aqui:

```
const $ = (e) => document.querySelector(e);

const res = $('#resultado');
const showResponse = (i) => res.innerHTML = i;

let isPlaying = false;

class Message {
  constructor() {
    this.comandos = [
      "atacar",
      "defender",
      "pegar",
      "ir para"
    ]
  }

  generateRandomNumber(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max + 1);
  }

  getResponse(type) {
    if(this.comandos.includes(type)) {
      switch(type) {
        case "ir para":
          console.log(type);
          break;
        case "atacar":
          showResponse("Você atacou");
          break;
        case "defender":
          showResponse("Você defendeu");
          break;
        case "pegar":
          showResponse("Você pegou");
          break;
      } 
    }
  }
}

class Weapon {
  constructor(name, damage, durability, weaponClass, effects = {}) {
    this.name = name;
    this.level = 0;

    this.damage = damage;

    this.durability = durability;

    this.effects = effects;

    this.weaponClass = weaponClass;
  }
}

class Armor {
  constructor(name, defense, durability, armorClass, effects = {}) {
    this.name = name;
    this.level = 0;

    this.defense = defense;

    this.durability = durability;

    this.armorClass = armorClass;

    this.effects = effects;
  }
}

class Enemy {
  constructor(name, level) {
    this.name = name;
    this.level = level;

    this.weapon1 = 'unarmed';
    this.weapon2 = 'unarmed';

    this.spells = {}

    this.armor = {
      helmet: armors["Cloth Set"]["Bandana"],
      chest: armors["Cloth Set"]["Cloth Armor"],
      gloves: armors["Cloth Set"]["Cloth Clamp"],
      boots: armors["Cloth Set"]["Light Boots"],
    }

    this.drops = {}
  }
}

const weapons = {
  swords: {
    "Simple Sword": new Weapon("Simple Sword", 10, 200, 'Sword')
  },
  twoHandedSwords: {
    "Two Handed Iron Sword": new Weapon("Two Handed Iron Sword", 35, 200, 'Two Handed Sword')
  },
  shields: {
    "Wooden Shield": new Armor("Wooden Shield", 20, 220, "Shield")
  }
}

const armors = {
  "Cloth Set": {
    "Bandana": new Armor("Bandana", 10, 220, "Helmet"),
    "Cloth Armor": new Armor("Cloth Armor", 20, 220, "Chest"),
    "Cloth Clamp": new Armor("Cloth Clamp", 15, 220, "Gloves"),
    "Light Boots": new Armor("Light Boots", 15, 220, "Boots")
  }
}

class Character {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.level = 1;

    this.weapon1 = 'unarmed';
    this.weapon2 = 'unarmed';

    this.spells = {}

    this.armor = {
      helmet: armors["Cloth Set"]["Bandana"],
      chest: armors["Cloth Set"]["Cloth Armor"],
      gloves: armors["Cloth Set"]["Cloth Clamp"],
      boots: armors["Cloth Set"]["Light Boots"],
    }

    this.inventory = {}
    this.gold = 0;

    this.isFighting = false;
    this.isTraveling = false;
    this.isShopping = false;
    this.isTalking = false;
  }
}

const runNextTurn = (query) => new Message().getResponse(query);
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  const userInput = $('input').value.toLowerCase();
  if(e.keyCode !== 13) return;
  showResponse("");
  if(!isPlaying && userInput === 'iniciar') {
    isPlaying = true;
    runNextTurn(userInput);
    showResponse("Você iniciou o jogo");
  } else if(!isPlaying && userInput !== 'iniciar') {
    showResponse("Você precisa iniciar o jogo primeiro");
  } else {
    runNextTurn(userInput);
  }

  return $('input').value = "";
})
```

Agradeço quem puder me ajudar nesse estudo

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o comando `confirm`, que funciona bem parecido com o `alert`, mas o `confirm` vai retornar se o usuário clicou no `OK` ou não, e você pode colocar esse comando dentro de um `IF..ELSE` para só continuar após uma ação do usuário.

```js
if (confirm("abrir o baú?")) {
  alert("+100g");
} else {
  alert("nada acontece");
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, eu realmente não sabia disso